# Turning on notification by switch button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, push-notification

I'm making a fragment that include some options and one of them is a switch button that turn on/off the option to daily notification with text of Daily tip that changes every day.
Anyone have an idea how to make this happen?

the switch button is on the Settings fragment

My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    displayView(R.id.nav_home);



}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return;
    }

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_main) instanceof Article) {
        ((Article) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_main)).handleOnBackPress();
        return;
    }

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        displayView(R.id.nav_home);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
}

private void displayView(int itemId) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new Article();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Recipes:
            fragment = new RecipesMain();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Converter:
            fragment = new Converter();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Videos:
            fragment = new Videos();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Tracking:
            fragment = new Tracking();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_TrainerMenu:
            fragment = new TrainerMenu();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Settings:
            fragment = new Settings();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_About:
            showDialog();
            break;

    }


    if (fragment != null) {
        final Fragment finalFragment = fragment;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
                        .replace(R.id.content_main, finalFragment)
                        .commit();
            }
        }, 0);
            }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }




@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    displayView(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}
private void showDialog()
{
    String text2 = "<font color=#6774bd>About SG50 App</font>";

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
    builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(text2));

    String text3 = "<font color=#A4A4A4>App made by Matan Cohen , Please contact me for any questions.</font>";//for custom message
    builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(text3));

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "תודה על שימוש", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
 }

}
```

fragment Settings.java:

```
    public class Settings extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("הגדרות");

 }
}
```

fragemnt_settings.XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
android:paddingBottom="30dp"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
android:paddingRight="30dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/daily_tip"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you!! Hope you can help me!

Comment: help? anyone? please?

Comment: Question is not clear !!!

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing this post with any new information you had, any new code you'd tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers didn't work would've bumped it to the top of the active queue. I've closed this one as a duplicate of the newer one, since you got answers there, but please just edit your original post next time.